# Como bloquear o teclado em jquery?

Tags: jquery

Como bloquear o teclado todo em jquery, especialmente a tecla esc para tela cheia, quero que não saia do fullscreen quando apertar esc.

exemplo:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { return false; }
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { return false; }    
});
```

É um cadastro de usuários e ele fica em um computador especifico só para o cadastro desses usuários, o pc não vai ter outra função a não ser essa.

Comment: Que navegador sai da tela cheia com ESC? Tentei o Chrome e o Firefox e ambos ignoram por padrão.

Comment: Todos saiem do fullscreen com ESC pelo que eu sei, pelo menos o internet explorer sai...

Comment: Já experimentou `$(document).keydown(function(e) { return false; });` ?

Comment: Ele continua saindo do fullscreen Sergio!

Comment: Provavelmente isso é independente do Browser, e sim uma função do OS. De qq maneira acho desaconselhável impedir o utilizador de sair de full-screen...

Comment: É um programa de cadastro e o usuario não pode sair da tela cheia, eu desabilitei o F1 com o cód: document.onhelp = function() { return(false); }
window.onhelp = function() { return(false); }
provavelmente tem alguma maneira de desabilitar o esc

Comment: Além de dar `return false;`, já tentou `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Já sim, e não deu certo...

Answer (score 5):

Por questões de segurança, nenhum browser vai permitir que uma página qualquer tire do usuário os controles mais básicos - como minimizar a janela, trocar para outra, etc. Nada impede, por exemplo, o uso de <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> - e a partir daí o usuário provavelmente vai conseguir fazer o que ele quiser. Não conheço a fundo o modo *fullscreen*, mas sei que o usuário precisa dar autorização pra entrar em tela cheia, e estou certo que o browser não permite que você sobrecarregue o comando para sair dela, seja ele qual for.

Sugiro que você "dê um passo pra trás" e avalie exatamente *que problema você está tentando resolver* ([e não somente a solução imaginada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/215)).

> É um programa de cadastro e o usuario não pode sair da tela cheia...

Cadastro no que? Não pode sair da tela cheia por que? É para resolver algum problema técnico no seu site/serviço/aplicativo (e se for, qual?) ou por razões de segurança? Existem alternativas? É importante que esses detalhes sejam bem pensados - e a solução mais apropriada empregada (seja usando recursos nativos do browser, ou recorrendo a plugins e/ou funcionalidades específicas do SO). Pois *no caso geral* a única resposta correta pra sua pergunta é: "é impossível bloquear totalmente o teclado em jQuery".

Comment: É um cadastro de usuários e ele fica em um computador especifico só para o cadastro desses usuários, o pc não vai ter outra função, estou pensando até em usar linguagens de software como Delphi para bolar esse sistema, preciso de sugestões...

Comment: @user3230262 Nesse caso, eu sugeriria investigar **browsers específicos pra um único site** ([*site-specific browser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser)). É uma funcionalidade que alguns browsers oferecem (dentre eles o IE9+ e o Google Chrome) para criar um atalho no desktop que abre uma janela do browser "simplificada" - sem menus, barra de endereço e coisas assim - restrita a acessar um único site ou domínio. Não posso indicar uma solução específica, pois não cheguei a usar nenhuma na prática, mas no site linkado (Wikipedia, em inglês) mostra algumas opções no fim da página

Comment: @user3230262 Além disso, procure saber como utilizar o "modo kiosk" ([*kiosk mode*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software)) do seu sistema operacional - de modo a impedir de fato o usuário de sair/trocar de aplicativo usando os controles usuais. Assim você vai ter um aplicativo que só acessa uma única página, e que não pode ser trocado por usuários não privilegiados.

Comment: mgibsonbr, vou pesquisar sobre kiosk mode e site-specific-browser, obrigado!